# How to check a mail message UID exist or not using JavaMail?

Tags: jakarta-mail

Please help me out how to find the mail exists or not.

Description: I've deleted a  mail but I've it's UID. Now how can I check whether a mail exists.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just marked it DELETED, you can still find it by searching for it by UID, see [UIDFolder.getMessageByUID](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/UIDFolder.html#getMessageByUID-long-).

If it was deleted by moving it to a Trash folder, the UID won't help you.  You'll need to search for it using some other attributes of the message such as the Message-Id.

If it was deleted and expunged, it's gone forever.